# Django User model is good enough to be used in production

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

Is it good to use django custom user model if you want to create a website for production purposes with some tweaks using AbstractBase

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Many people use custom user models in production, and the docs [recommend that you use a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) to give flexibility later. Why do you think it would not be good enough for production?

Answer (score 0):

I think so, if you don't need modify it later.

However, you can extending the User model, even you don't use any custom field at the moment. In this way, you will be able to add any field in the future.